What is error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token?
I clone this open source project https://github.com/balfieri/cordic. I encountered issue below after following README to run $ g++ -std=c++17 -o test_basic test_basic.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++17 -o test_basic test_basic.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/cmath:45,
                 from Cordic.h:24,
                 from freal.h:43,
                 from test_basic.cpp:23:
Cordic.h:152:10: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘==’ token
  152 |     bool issubnormal( const T& x ) const;                               // fpclassify() is FP_SUBNORMAL
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
Cordic.h:2319:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
 2319 | inline bool Cordic<T,FLT>::issubnormal( const T& x ) const
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from freal.h:43,
                 from test_basic.cpp:23:
Cordic.h: In instantiation of ‘Cordic<T, FLT>::Cordic(uint32_t, uint32_t, bool, uint32_t, uint32_t) [with T = long int; FLT = double; uint32_t = unsigned int]’

https://github.com/balfieri/cordic/blob/master/Cordic.h#L152
bool issubnormal( const T& x ) const;

https://github.com/balfieri/cordic/blob/master/Cordic.h#L2318
template< typename T, typename FLT >
inline bool Cordic<T,FLT>::issubnormal( const T& x ) const                                     
{
    return fpclassify( x ) == FP_SUBNORMAL;
}

I have no idea Why error occur because I think there is no syntax error.  I appreciate if anyone can told me how to solve it.

You're getting a name conflict with a (non-standard) macro called subnormal. The easiest option is to rename the function to something else, and report a bug to the developer. Your IDE can tell you what defines this macro, if you're curious.

This is not a [mcve]

There is another way of solving this. Just add parenthesis around the function's name as shown in my answer and this demo

The problem is that there's a non-standard macro with the same name subnormal that conflicts with the member function you're declaring.
Solution 1

I appreciate if anyone can told me how to solve it.

You can solve this by adding parenthesis around the member function's declaration to make it different from the macro with the same name as shown below:
template<typename T> struct Cordic
{
    //---vvvvvvvvvvvv------->added parenthesis here
    bool (issubnormal)( const T& x ) const;
};
template< typename T>
//----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------->added parenthesis here
inline bool (Cordic<T>::issubnormal)( const T& x ) const                                     
{
    return {};
}

Working demo
Solution 2
Another option is to rename the option to some other name that doesn't conflict with the already existing name.

Solution 3: Download https://github.com/balfieri/cordic/pull/2 :-)

@TedLyngmo Yup and if the developer of that project don't want to undef for some reason, they can use the parenthesis workaround. Btw, in the pull request a comment mentioning this post could be added perhaps. :)

True. I added that to the PR message
